# How To Perform array_search In Multi Dimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code :

```
$order_list = array ( array ("tangible", 1, 8, 33, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 9, 8, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 6, 3, 24, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 6, 2, 10, NULL),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 17, 11, 28000));

$key = array_search(3, array_column($order_list, $order_list[2]));
```

and I want to get the value of `$order_list[$i][3]` based on `$order_list[$i][2]`.

for example, if I put :

`3` I will get `24` in return

`9` I will get `8` in return

and so on...

I tried to use array_search :

```
$key = array_search(3, array_column($order_list, $order_list[2]));
```

but I got this error :

```
Warning: array_column(): The column key should be either a string or an integer in /home/***/public_html/***.php on line 8

Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home/***/public_html/***.php on line 8
```

how to perform array_serach in this case? thanks before.

Comment: what will be output for the 6?

Comment: 6 is not the key to perform search, bro. 6 is actually `vendor_id`. and 3 and 2 are `product_id`. we don't do search based on `vendor_id`, but based on `product_id`. and the result is 24 or 10. which are number of pcs.

Comment: see my answer hope this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a general purpose function to get next value of current value in 2'd array. have a look on below function. Also look at variable description of function to understand input in function:

```
/***
 * @param array $array input array
 * @param $search_value value that need to be searched
 * @param $search_index index of inner array where current value exists
 * @return next value of current value
 */
function getNextSequence(array $array, $search_value, $search_index)
{
    $result = null;
    $key = array_search($search_value, array_column($array, $search_index));
    if ($key !== false) {
        $result = (isset($array[$key][$search_index + 1])) ? $array[$key][$search_index + 1] : null;
    }

    return $result;
}

$order_list = array(
    array("tangible", 1, 8, 33, 19000),
    array("tangible", 1, 9, 8, 19000),
    array("tangible", 6, 3, 24, 19000),
    array("tangible", 6, 2, 10, NULL),
    array("tangible", 1, 17, 11, 28000)
);

var_dump(getNextSequence($order_list, 3, 2)); //output: int(24)
var_dump(getNextSequence($order_list, 9, 2)); //output: int(8)
var_dump(getNextSequence($order_list, 10, 2)); //output: Null
var_dump(getNextSequence($order_list, 2, 2)); //output: int(10)
```

Comment: bro, I tried : var_dump(getNextSequence($order_list, 8, 2)); this should give me 33 as result. but why your code give me NULL?

Comment: it seems your code skip the first row of $order_list

Comment: @RobertHanson its because `if($key)` condition its escaping 0 as well. Corrected my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$search = 9;

$order_list = array ( array ("tangible", 1, 8, 33, 19000),
                  array ("tangible", 1, 9, 8, 19000),
                  array ("tangible", 6, 3, 24, 19000),
                  array ("tangible", 6, 2, 10, NULL),
                  array ("tangible", 1, 17, 11, 28000));




foreach ($order_list as $string){

    if (in_array($search,$string)){
       //repsonse here
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

another way.....

```
$search = 9;

$order_list = array ( array ("tangible", 1, 8, 33, 19000),
                  array ("tangible", 1, 9, 8, 19000),
                  array ("tangible", 6, 3, 24, 19000),
                  array ("tangible", 6, 2, 10, NULL),
                  array ("tangible", 1, 17, 11, 28000));




foreach ($order_list as $string){
    if ($string[2] == $search){
    print_r( $string);  
    }  
}
```